# Cannot convert value of type JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-context

In my project, I have configured spring beans as follows. (To get the `DataSource` via `JNDI`). And the below configurations worked fine when I used `spring 3.2.5` along with `hibernate 4`.

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/jdbc/mydb"/>
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.core.system_configuration.implGeneral.bean.*"/>
        <property name="configLocations" value="implGeneral/sysConfigHibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>
```

However, now when I try to update Spring to 5.1.8 and Hibernate 5, I get the below error.

```
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
```

why `org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean` cant be casted to `javax.sql.DataSource` . Does anyone have an idea on this?

UPDATED:
complete error log is as follows

```
13:59:30,939 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ruleCacheControler' defined in class path resource [implGeneral/spring-config-systemconfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleHibernatePersister' while setting constructor argument;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ruleHibernatePersister' defined in class path resource [implGeneral/spring-config-systemconfig.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [implGeneral/spring-config-systemconfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.JndiRmiProxyFactoryBean' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace. Also the upgrade entails quite some versions (4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0. 5.1, so quite a range) so you might want to check the upgrade notes for all of these to see what changed.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply. complete log is added to the question.

Comment: There should be nothing preventing this to work (unless you forgot something from them igration guides I mentioned). Also I strongly suggest using 5.1.16 as the latest 5.1 version.